# Jquery disable click if hover too long

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery game that you can view here [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/DHPQT/)

The game starts by you entering a number in a text field. then you click the play button.

After clicking the play button a set of square appear each rotating random numbers, click on the square that has your number to build up your score, miss 3 times and you are done.

I added the game to my site, you can view it here [link text](http://www.gamerholic.com/pickanumber.php)

the problem I'm having is that my site members will just keep the cursor on one box and wait for their number to appear in that one box. Which ruins the game. Is there a way to make it so they can't click on the same box more than once in a row. They'll have to go click another box before they can come back to this one.

here's my complete script

```
var hitCount = 0,
    missCount = 0;

function IsNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(n);
}

$("#getit").click(function() {
    var hitCount = 0,
        missCount = 0;
    $('#hitcount').text(0);
    $('#misscount').text(0);

    $('#message').hide(100);
    var li = [],
        intervals = 0,
        n = parseInt($('#MyNumber').val());

    var intervalId = -1;
    if (IsNumeric(n)) {
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
            li[intervals++ % li.length].text(Math.random() > .1 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + n) + (n / 2)) : n).attr('class', '')    ;
        }, <?php echo $time ?>);
    }

    $('#randomnumber').empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        li.push($('<li />').appendTo('#randomnumber'));
    }

    $('#randomnumber').delegate("li", "click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
            if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
                $this.addClass('correct');
                $('#hitcount').text(++hitCount);
            } else {
                $this.addClass('wrong');
                $('#misscount').text(++missCount);
            }

            //New code If the missCount > 3 stop the game and save the value
            if(missCount>=<?php echo $limit ?>){
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                $('#randomnumber').undelegate("li", "click");
                // Use a ajax request to save the values

                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'FBhighscore_hwnd.php',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: {
                        tgameid: $('#tgameid').val(),MyNumber: $('#MyNumber').val(),totalHits: hitCount
                    },
                    success : function(data){
                        $('#waiting').hide(500);
                        $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                            .text(data.msg).show(500);
                        if (data.error === true)
                            $('#loginForm').show(500);
                        else
                            $('#send').hide(500);
                    },
                    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $('#waiting').hide(500);
                        $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                            .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                        $('#loginForm').show(500);
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        $this.addClass('clicked');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the possibility of marking a square as 'inactive' once a player has clicked on it and then only re-activating it after either mouseout or mouseover on another one of the squares?

Something like this:

```
$('.gamesquare').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('disabledSquare')) {

        // Do your game logic for clicks here

        $(this).addClass('disabledSquare');
    }
}

$('.gamesquare').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('disabledSquare');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DHPQT/7/)

I have it setup so that the person actually has to try to select their number on each block before a new set of blocks will appear. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: thanks bro, the option to click on every box before generating a new set of boxes makes the game easier. The hover stuff is just not going to work due to the intervals. I'm exploring new options like deducting points if the users number appears in a box that they didn't click, this way they are forced to play all the boxes not just one or 2.

Comment: Let me know when the games done so I can check it out. If you need help with other stuff hit me up and I'll help you debug.